# How do I get EBS volume ids that are attached to an OpsWorks instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm using OpsWorks to deploy a bunch of applications and I want to tag the instances and all of their associated resources. I'm using the opscode aws cookbook (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/aws) to tag my instances and that works fine using the following recipe:

```
include_recipe 'aws'

custom_tags = node.fetch('aws_tag', {}).fetch('tags', nil)
instance_id = node.fetch('ec2', {}).fetch('instance_id', nil)

unless custom_tags.nil? || custom_tags.empty?
  aws_resource_tag 'tag instance' do
    tags custom_tags
    resource_id instance_id
    action :update
  end
end
```

I'd like to extend this recipe to tag EBS volumes that are attached to the instance. `aws_resource_tag()` can tag instances, snapshots, and volumes, but I need to provide it a list of the volumes to tag.

How can I get the volume ids attached to the instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-opsworks-instance.html so you'll probably just have to use the standard ohai data. Connect to the machine and run `ohai ec2` and you'll see the full metadata tree.

Comment: There's no EBS information in the metadata produced when I run `sudo opsworks-agent-cli get_json`.

Comment: Ohai just mines whatever data exists on the Amazon metadata server.

Comment: The Ohai binary wasn't installed by default with the instance. All of Amazon's documentation says to use `opsworks-agent-cli` to gather information about the instance. If we're talking about the same thing, it seems like Amazon doesn't include that data at all.

Comment: Ohai is an internal component of Chef, it is not something related (directly) with OpsWorks.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to access any information about the EBS volumes attached to the instance. I've tried dumping the contents of `node` to the log to see what's in it and there's nothing there about EBS.

Comment: You can find information on the root device under block-device-mappings I think. For non-root EBS volumes you have to query the API yourself.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need know [OpsWorks automatically tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/tagging.html) Layer or Stack resources associated but the Tags cannot currently be applied to the root, or default, EBS volume of an instance.

If you using OpsWorks for Windows Stack, I suggest install the following cookbook from Supermarket:

File **metadata.rb**

```
depends 'aws', '4.2.2'
depends 'ohai', '4.2.3'
depends 'compat_resource', '12.19.1'
```

Next add to your stack a IAM role with necessary permission to perform [list-tags for OpsWorks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/list-tags.html) and [create-tags in the EC2 service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html).

At the end you can use this recipes **add-tags.rb**:

```
Chef::Log.info("******TAGS VOLUME******")
#Chef::Log.level = :debug
instance = search("aws_opsworks_instance", "self:true").first
stack = search("aws_opsworks_stack").first
arnstack = "#{stack['arn']}"
cmd = "aws opsworks list-tags --resource-arn #{arnstack} --region eu-west-1"
Chef::Log.info("****** #{arnstack} ******")
batch  'find_tags' do
  cwd "C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSCLI"
  code <<-EOH
  #{cmd} > C:\\tmp\\res.json
  EOH
end
if ::File.exist?('C:\\tmp\\res.json')
  myjsonfile = ::File.read('C:\\tmp\\res.json').chomp
  data = JSON.parse("#{myjsonfile}")
  data['Tags'].each do |key, value|
    aws_resource_tag 'Boot Volume' do
        resource_id lazy {instance['root_device_volume_id']}
        tags(key => value)
    end
  end
end
```

That recipe add all TAG founded on stack only to root volume of my instance.